# How to show Pyspark DataFrames nicely in Jupyter?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using Pyspark in a Jupyter notebook (just following tutorials for now, nothing complicated).

Online, I see lots of pictures of nicely rendered DataFrames in Jupyter (using the `display()` function), but when I use that on my system, all I see are lines like this: `DataFrame[id: string, name: string, age: bigint]`

[image: picture of my Jupyter interface, with examples using both display and print, none of which show the contents of the DataFrame)]

I uimported the following librairies:

```py
import pyspark

from functools import reduce
from graphframes import *
from IPython.display import display, HTML
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, when
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
```

How can I display my DataFrames nicely? Or at least so I can see their content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `df.show()` for example in your case you can try doing `edges.show()` or `g.vertices.show()` it should render a basic table. If you are looking for nicer and more advance visualization of your data then you can install [sparkmagic](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic) which has a built-in visualization library ([autoviz](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/blob/master/autovizwidget/examples/autoviz.ipynb))

Here is a nice example [notebook](https://github.com/qubole/jupyter/blob/master/examples/notebooks/pyspark/GettingStarted_PySpark.ipynb) demonstrating how you can combine [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) data frame with [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/) to render some nice visualizations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

By nicely do you mean, as HTML table or charts? If you meant HTML tables, you dont have to do anything special since pandas dataframes are by default renderd as nice HTML table

[image]

If you meant, charts, you will have to either use other charting libraries or use sparkmagic/autoviz.

Comment: see that's what I thought, but it didn't do that for me